# Retrieving Asset Information from Confirmed Transaction RPC Response for Compressed NFTs

Tags: nft, python, cnft, compression

Currently working on a project involving Solana and its NFT functionality, specifically dealing with compressed NFTs. I am trying to understand how to retrieve the asset information (including the asset_id) from the RPC response of a confirmed transaction using Python.

RPC response of confirmed transaction includes details about the transaction, such as the sender, recipient, amount transferred, and program logs. In the case of NFT transactions, the program logs contain the metadata of the NFT involved in the transaction.

However, I am having trouble understanding how to extract the asset_id and other relevant information from the transaction receipt. Specifically, for compressed NFTs, the asset_id is not directly included in the transaction receipt. Instead, it is derived from the address of the Merkle Tree and the leaf index of the Compressed NFT in the Merkle tree.

Could anyone guide me on how to extract the asset_id and other relevant information from the transaction receipt of a confirmed transaction involving compressed NFTs using Python? Any example code or resources would be greatly appreciated.

Example [transaction](https://xray.helius.xyz/tx/3EiyiW2ry4FvPnuNMJRdWBwwNJdPzWraDaiApc4vhJ82P13pMwNueTxD9FnCY8pXBZ8ixiiS31d53aNYhLNVuEZt?network=mainnet), you can see the rpc response on `Advance` section of Transaction data.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!